# Windows VFP project re-write - can ASP.Net MVC support the requirements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My company administers health care provider networks for health care payors (each payor has a network of providers available to their members).  When a health care provider's qualifications or other information change, those changes need to be communicated to the payor(s) with whom they are contracted.  Currently we use a legacy Visual FoxPro application to manage producing the data change files (MS Excel format) to be sent to the payor.

Evolution of the business model has required us to begin the process of re-writing the application. I was wondering it this is the type of project for which ASP.Net MVC would be a good fit.  I'm primarily a Windows developer, but my manager has often expressed an interest in moving our line of business applications to our intranet for ease maintenance and better accessibility.  He gets no argument from me, as I've wanted to work on a web-based project for a while, now.

My primary concern is whether or not an ASP.Net MVC application could properly support the task of executing a SQL Server stored procedure (no-brainer, of course) to retrieve the provider change data and produce numerous MS Excel files from that data (one for each payor) in one operation.  Those files would need to be either saved locally or generated on a network share.

As I recall, there are concerns pertaining to accessing local resources from a web app, so is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Any .NET application, web or otherwise, can connect to a database and write to a file system.  It's not really clear based on the description what would be a problem here.

Comment: I suppose I could have distilled this down to, "Can an ASP.Net MVC web page generate multiple Excel files and save them to a local/network directory on the user's computer?"  So your answer to that would be yes, then?

Comment: You have a few options, depending on various factors not mentioned here.  If generating the files happens quickly, you can zip them into one file and respond to the user with that one file.  If the files need to be separate, you can store them on the server and provide the user with links to download them.  If the process takes a long time, you can store the result on the server and send the user a notification with a link to download the result.  There are many approaches to take.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the ideas.  Sounds like saving the files to a network share may be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MVC app running on IIS web server can access any file or folder on the network that the app pool identity in IIS has read/write permission to. So, as long as you can have access to properly make the IIS settings that are required, you can own any file or folder anywhere you have access to.

I'm a 20+ year FoxPro guy, and I've been doing genuine OOP style programming in VFP for years, all because of what I learned from C# and .Net MVC web apps when I took to learning them starting in 2008 right when MVC was just coming out.

Look, FoxPro is awesome, and I love, and still work in it regularly for one large CRUD app, but guess what... I love C# and .Net too, and I have enough first hand experience on 2 pretty good sized .NET MVC business apps MVC apps to say with 100% certainty that anything I ever did in my VFP apps I can do in C#. You lose a few things, but you gain a lot more, especially when it comes to the availability of .Net libraries and the power of writing business CRUD apps in the MVC framework and a web browser for the UI, and javascript, oh, my, javascript!

The UI possibilities with web apps is really powerful, but it is a totally different mindset fro the FoxPro drag and drop form designer to jump into a world of rendered UI pages from the Razor view engine, or using client side tools like Knockout (one I really like), or Angular, or possibly Aurelia if it catches some nice adoption when it reaches RTM.

So, choosing ".Net" is only part of the choice. That's the back end stuff, and some UI stuff if you're going to use Razor views, but the harder choice in my opinion is what UI strategy are you going to choose. Oh, and don't forget about deciding if you need an API and channel all your data hits through the API rather than old-school MVC page post-backs to hit the Controller and re-render the UI page from scratch. Oh my, that's already legacy style coding right there. It has it's place, but it can also make for a really clunky UI experience.

And, be sure you choose C# and *not* Visual Basic .Net.

Oh. My. Goodness.... Have fun, my friend.  I have been!

Comment: Thanks so much for your insights.  I also began my programming career (professionally, anyway) with FoxPro in the mid-90's.  Around 2000 my current employer changed our official platform to VB for all new development.  Over the last couple years I've enjoyed a bit more freedom in what languages and platforms I use, so it's been C# wherever possible.  I'll always have a soft spot in my heart for FoxPro, but I've been itching to re-write this app for years, now.